# Generate new Ethereum Wallet in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ethereum, go-ethereum, bitcoin-testnet

Are you familiar with ethereum and web3js-api in node js?

I used the framework sails, and i am a little bit confused how to generate a new account like (https://www.myetherwallet.com/). For now i used web3js-api v.1.0.0. I can get current account and balance. i try to create new account, but it return error, says create is not a function, etc.

i used testnet, how can i connect it to metamask (Rinkeby Network)? So if i generate new account, the account will appear in metamask account list also.

If you know, please share.
Thanks.

[image: error]

Comment: You should post the code you are using to try and create a new account.

Comment: var newaccount = web3.eth.personal.newAccount('!@superpassword',
  function(err, res){
    console.log(res)
})

Comment: MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ethereum-wallet

```
let myWallet = new EthereumWallet() // using MyEtherAPI.com web3 HTTP provider
```

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form, Ethereum wallet is just a single private key.

1. Generate [a random 256-bit integer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82926/how-to-generate-a-new-ethereum-private-key-from-a-command-line) - this is your private key
2. web3.js functions can import any private key with [privateKeyToAccount](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount) - This will derive an Ethereum public key and Ethereum address, which is just trimmed public key, for you
3. Now web3.js can use your private key to sign transactions and messages